# Solving $y'(x)+y^2=1+x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve $y'(x)+y^2(x)=1+x^2$ using the property of the Ricatti equation that lets me find the general solution from a particular solution. A particular solution is $y_1(x)=x$, so using the substitution $y=y_1+1/v$ the Ricatti equation $y'(x)=A(x)y^2(x)+B(x)y(x)+C(x)$ becomes $v'(x)+(B(x)+2A(x)y_1(x))v(x)=-A(x)$. In this case that gives $v'(x)-2xv(x)=-x^2-1$. The problem I'm having is that this 1st order linear ODE is too hard to solve on its own for this course so something must be wrong. This is the method I'm supposed to use specifically. Solution apparently involves erf function which can't be right.

Comment: The solution is given by $$y(x)=\frac{e^{-x^2}}{c_1+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(x)}+x$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note for OP:** Your ODE for $v(x)$ is not correct.

The given ODE is $$y'+y^2=1+x^2$$ which is Riccati equation with one solution as $y=x$
So if we put $y=x+\frac{1}{v}$ in it, we get
$$\frac{dv}{dx}-2xv=1$$ its integrating factor is $e^{-x^2}$ so the solution for $v(x)$ is
$$v=e^{x^2} \int e^{-x^2} dx +C e^{x^2}= e^{x^2} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} ~erf(x)+ C e^{x^2}.$$ Finally, we get
$$y=x+\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} ~erf(x)+ C}.$$
As suggested by @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner.

Comment: Thanks, I messed up the A,B,C ordering it seems.